# how to connect mongoDB with params from request

Tags: typescript, import, module, export, nestjs

i'm a new bie with Nestjs, I want each req to the nestjs server to connect a separate database according to the req's params, I think I can use mongooseModule.forRoot in the submodules but can't import param to connect, or use mongoose. createConnection then nestjs cannot resolve
i need help, if anyone can help me,
I thank everyone for reading

Comment: Please add the code you're trying with. That will help SO users to understand the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.